# Directory.Exists() fails with to recognize nonexistent folder (backward slash error)

Tags: c#, directory, exists

I am using `Directory.Exists()` to check the existence of a folder, and encounter a failure of that method.  My command is:

```
if (Directory.Exists(myFolder) == false) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(myFolder, "Invalid Log Folder path", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand); 
}

if (Directory.Exists(myFolder) == true) 
{ 
     MessageBox.Show(myFolder, "Valid Folder path"); 
}
```

When myFolder is `C:\Documents and Settings\UserID\My Documents` it returns `TRUE`.

When myFolder is `C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\My Documents` it returns `FALSE` (given that `xxx` does not exist).

However, when myFolder is `C:\\Documents and Settings\UserID\My Documents` it also returns `TRUE`.

The double backward slashes next to `C:` must have invalidated the test.  However, `Directory.Exists()` fails to recognize that.

With more `\` it still encounters the same problem.

I just cannot understand how this failure occurs.  I am using VS2008 with .NET 3.5.

Comment: Does the account `UserID` exist? How is `myFolder` initialized? Are those paths what the string contains? Is that what you typed in the string literal? What you're asking isn't very clear.

Comment: `it also returns TRUE.` Seems you solved your own problem...

Comment: Is `myFolder` a string literal? If so, are you using the @ prefix?

Comment: the double backslash is not technically invalid. Actually, this means that you add a relative path in your path, to the root. It's like `..` that means direct parent, or `.` which means self. `\` means root

Comment: *"Directory.Exists() fails to recognize nonexistent folder"* - I imagine it would...

Comment: And furthermore, why in the world do you view this behavior as a problem?  Another nitpick; `if(someBoolean == true)` is teh same as saying `if( false == true)` or `if(true == true)`.  Save yourself some typing and just evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Open command prompt
2. enter the command `cd c:\\\\\\\\\`

You will find it's perfectly acceptable.

Another test:

1. Open command prompt
2. try `cd c:\\\\\\\\\\\\temp`

You will now be in the c:\temp directory, assuming you have one.

Last one:

1. Open command prompt
2. Try `cd c:\\\\\\\\\\\\\inetpub\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\logs`

You are now in the c:\inet\logs directory, assuming you have one.

It seems you had incorrect expectations about how the `Directory.Exists()` method behaves.

Any number of '\' is interpretted as a single '\' in commands and those methods, and is perfectly acceptable input.

Comment: but that is not how Windows Explorer operates.